# Postscreen dnsbl logs

Tags: logs, postfix

I'm using postscreen dnsbl configuration to block some spam:

```
postscreen_blacklist_action = drop
postscreen_dnsbl_threshold = 4
postscreen_dnsbl_action = enforce
postscreen_dnsbl_sites =
    zen.spamhaus.org
    b.barracudacentral.org
    bl.spameatingmonkey.net
    bl.spamcop.net
    dnsbl.sorbs.net
    dnsbl-1.uceprotect.net
    dnsbl-2.uceprotect.net
    dnsbl-3.uceprotect.net
    spamsources.fabel.dk
    rbl.abuse.ro
    bl.blocklist.de
    bl.0spam.org
    truncate.gbudb.net
    spam.dnsbl.anonmails.de
    cbl.abuseat.org
    hostkarma.junkemailfiltebeltimeblacklist.com=127.0.0.2
    rbl.dns-servicios.com
    rbl.interserver.net
    spam.spamrats.com
    ubl.unsubscore.com
    dnsbl.dronebl.org
    z.mailspike.net
    bl.mailspike.net
    dnsbl.zapbl.net
    dnsbl.cobion.com
    db.wpbl.info
```

And in my logs I have this example of blocked email(a non-spam one):

```
    blocked using dnsbl-2.uceprotect.net
    blocked using spam.dnsbl.anonmails.de
```

So only two of them, not four. And I want to know if there is a way to log more information about the threshold for each rejected email(maybe for each dnsbl_site).

My postfix version: 3.6.4;